# How to install and setup LDAP via command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap

When I use `sudo apt-get -y install slapd` 和 `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd` to install and configure slapd in ubuntu16.04, I met this situation,

[image]

[image]

How can I make this GUI （choose or input） become totally command line?

Or just one click to install and configure ldap ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And this question should rather go to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 1):

For 14.04 I use commands

```
apt-get update && \
echo 'slapd/root_password password password' | debconf-set-selections &&\
echo 'slapd/root_password_again password password' | debconf-set-selections && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils
```

Try it.